# How to write a middleware for the functions in typescript namespace

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, namespaces, javascript-namespaces

I want to write a middleware for the namespace in typescript. So when any function in the namespace is called, middleware should trigger and check if the intended function can be executed. Example:

```
namespace Foo.Bar {
  function middleware(next) {
     if (enabled) next();
  }
  export function baz() {
     // Do Something
  }
}
```

If i make call to baz `Foo.Bar.baz()`, i want my middleware method to trigger first.
If it is module, i can export an object of functions like this:

```
export {baz: middleware}
```

But namespace will not permit to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: can you provide an example in the question

Comment: ``namespace Foo.Bar {
  applyMiddleWare(next) {
    if (enabled) next();
  }
   export function trigger() {
     // So Something
  }
}``

So when the trigger method is called, i want a middleware function to execute first. And that middle ware will decide whether or not to execute the trigger function.

Comment: the question will soon be closed unless you edit it with a better explanation and some code.

Comment: If I can maintain Foo.Bar and call function, I can update it to be class. So I have to still be calling Foo.Bar.baz() as all my application is built using this and I don't want to change this naming convention now.

Answer (score 1):

If you're ok about some "dirty-dirty" js-like coding, then the next approach might help you:

```
namespace Foo.Bar {
    export function middleware(next) {
        alert("middleware");
        next();
    }
    export function baz() {
        alert("baz");
        // Do Something
    }
}

// Simple call
Foo.Bar.baz();

// "Middleware magic"
const origMethod = Foo.Bar.baz;
Foo.Bar.baz = () => {
    Foo.Bar.middleware(origMethod);
}
// Middleware call
Foo.Bar.baz();
```

It can be tested on the [TS playground site](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=namespace%20Foo.Bar%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20function%20middleware(next)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert(%22middleware%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20next()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20function%20baz()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert(%22baz%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Do%20Something%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Simple%20call%0D%0AFoo.Bar.baz()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%22Middleware%20magic%22%0D%0Aconst%20origMethod%20%3D%20Foo.Bar.baz%3B%0D%0AFoo.Bar.baz%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Foo.Bar.middleware(origMethod)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Middleware%20call%0D%0AFoo.Bar.baz()%3B).

Comment: This is great. But i don't think this is the best approach for my application. Can we maintain the namespace `Foo.Bar` and have a class that exports an object of functions?

Comment: If you need to run your code before the original code is executed every time somebody calls the Foo.Bar.baz() method, there is no other way, except creating the new function instead of the original Foo.Bar.baz.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using a static class and method [decorators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html).

foo.ts

```
// method decorator    
function middleware() {
    return function(target: any, propertyKey: string) {
        // exec middleware
        console.log('middleware')
    }
}

export namespace Foo {

    export class Bar {
        constructor() {
            throw new Error('Instantiating is not allowed');
        }

        @middleware()
        static baz() {
            console.log('after middleware');
        }
    }
}
```

This will still remain your namespace convention.

index.ts

```
import { Foo } from './foo';

Foo.Bar.baz();
```

This middleware will trigger before the method `baz` is called. However, if your middleware is `async` and you need the decorated method to wait for the middleware to be finished, you can change the middleware to something like the follow:

```
function middleware() {
    return function (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
        let fn = descriptor.value;

        return {
            configurable: true,
            get() {
                return () => {
                    console.log('middleware');

                    wait(1000).then(() => wait(1000)).then(() => fn.call());
                }
            }
        }
    };
}

function wait(millis: number) {
    console.log(`wait ${millis}ms`);

    return new Promise<void>(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, millis);
    });
}
```

Or, if you prefer `async` and `await`, you can change the `get` function to return a function of type `Promise<void>` instead:

```
get() {
    return async () => {
        console.log('middleware')

        await wait(1000);

        await wait(1000);

        fn.call();
    }
}
```